# TestNG Intellij Plugin -- Only one of the tests running

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I have a TestNG ml file like shown below:

```
<suite name="MyRegression" verbose="1"
parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
<listeners>
    <listener
        class-name="com.company.testinfrastructure.testdrivers.listeners.Interceptor" />
</listeners>

<test name="US">
    <parameter name="site" value="US"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.AlertTests"></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="UK">
    <parameter name="site" value="UK"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class
                name="com.AlertTests"></class>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

I right-click on the file in Intellij, and then click then "Run" using the TestNG plugin. However, only the "US" test runs. The "UK" test doesn't run. If I have 10 tests, then only the first test runs, while the others don't appear. I have coworkers who have the same testng file and use Intellij, and can run all tests fine on their machine/

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation? It works fine on my side with test project.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario as provided by you is working as expected with IntelliJ, java v11 & TestNG v7.6.1 with below source code & output as,

TestNG XML File

```
<suite name="MyRegression" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
    <test name="US">
        <parameter name="site" value="US"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.testng.AlertTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="UK">
        <parameter name="site" value="UK"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.testng.AlertTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Test Runner Class

```
package org.testng;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AlertTests {

    @Test()
    @Parameters("site")
    public void echoName(String site) {
        System.out.println(site);
    }
}
```

Output

```
US
UK
```

Image
[image]